# Верстка меню

Tags: html, css

Как сверстать выделение активного пункта такого вида
[image]
(макет есть)
?

Comment: ul.menu li { }

ul.menu li a { }

ul.menu li a span { }

Comment: @Palmervan в смысле? меня интересует, как сделать этот фигурный прямоугольник у активного пункта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/tn4CW/) с :before и :after.
Работает во всех браузерах, которые у меня есть :)

ЗЫ код не причесывал, в любом случае это не конечный вариант, судя по макету...

Comment: понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Либо оборачивать ссылки в дополнительные элементы, которым задавать разные "background", или использовать псевдоклассы :before и :after.

Comment: Получается, чтобы задать такое оформление, ссылку придется завернуть в три доп.элемента, для которых задать разные бэкграунды для левой части, для правой части и для центральной?

Comment: Да, но не обязательно три.

Comment: Каким образом?